# How to locate instances within an EKS cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, nodes, cluster-computing, aws-cli

How can I see which instances are associated with an EKS cluster?

I can use the AWS CLI to list cluster names and describe clusters, but how can I see which instances are actually in the cluster?

`aws eks list-clusters --region us-east-1`

```
    "clusters": [
        "foo-cluster",
        "bar-cluster"
    ]
}
```

`aws eks describe-cluster --name foo-cluster`

```
{
    "cluster": {
        "name": "foo-cluster",
        "arn": "arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:12345:cluster/foo-cluster",
        "createdAt": 1554068824.493,
        "version": "1.13",
        "endpoint": "https://12345.abc.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/foo-cluster12345",
        "resourcesVpcConfig": {
            "subnetIds": [
                "subnet-45678",
                "subnet-34567",
                "subnet-23456",
                "subnet-12345"
            ],
            "securityGroupIds": [
                "sg-12345"
            ],
            "vpcId": "vpc-12345"
        },
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "certificateAuthority": {
            "data": "zubzubzub="
        },
        "platformVersion": "eks.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't from the `aws eks ...` CLI specifically. Kubernetes nodes are basically EC2 instances, so hopefully, you tagged your instances appropriately when you created them, typically with an Autoscaling Group with a tool like [eksctl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html).

Your instances typically will have a 'Name' tag that is the same as the worker node name. So you could do:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=node-name
```

Alternatively, you can get either the `NAME` or the `INTERNAL-IP` of the node with:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o=wide
```

Then you can find your instances based on that:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-dns-name,Values=NAME
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values=INTERNAL-IP
```

Alternative, you can query the autoscaling group:

```
$ aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names <your-asg-name> | jq .AutoScalingGroups[0].Instances[].InstanceId
```